# How to automount SMB share in OS X

Tags: smb, macos, automount

I am running OS X Lion.  I have the following line in my /etc/fstab:

`//darren:q@acid/home   /acid   smbfs   nodev,nosuid,auto`

If I run `mount -a`, the share mounts correctly, but if I just reboot the computer, the drive does not mount.

The drive in question is an Ubuntu SMB share.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 5):

I ran across [this today](http://www.dforge.net/2012/08/07/create-a-permanent-smb-mount-in-osx/) which is one way to do it.

In summary for Mountain Lion:

1. Edit the file /etc/auto_master
2. Within add `/- auto_smb`
3. Create /etc/auto_smb
4. Within add `/Volumes/mount_point -fstype=smbfs,soft ://user:pass@smbserver/share`

The author goes onto mention a second method using the vifs command, but I've never tried that one and it seems to do something of a pre-mount at bootup. You still have to touch the Volume for it to completely mount.

Lastly, the author states that "soft" should be used in step 4 above because failures to mount will cause the bootup to hang.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind summarizing the instructions provided in the link? It is often good to include a link with your answer, however, links can break over time, so it best that they are not solely the answer.

Comment: will `mount -a` work if for some reason it didnt mounted on startup ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to mount the drive once, then go to Settings Panel and Users & Groups. There you can add it. If you hide it, it will mount but don't open the finder screen upon logging in.

[image]

Comment: He's not talking about Amazon Cloud Drive; your response does not apply to regular filesystem mounts.

Comment: It does. Screenshot only show the screen where you should do it, not the program.

Comment: OK.  How then do you automount an SMB drive via Settings > Users & Groups > Login Items  I've done it via the accepted answer (/etc/auto_master and /etc/auto_smb), but I don't know what program you would put into Settings > Users & Groups > Login Items to make it work.  A bash script of your own devising?  If so, what would the script say?

Comment: Just use Finder to mount it, then you can add it to the screen above.

Comment: oh, now I see what you mean (when you just said "then you can add it" it wasn't clear you meant "drag the mounted volume onto the Login Items list"). I didn't know that volumes could be added to that list ... but, clearly, they can.  That's a great tip, thanks!