# mount list grows endlessly on automount / autofs setup

Tags: macos, mac, smb, automount, autofs

I have configured macOS (Catalina 10.15.3) to automount 4 SMB network shares with autofs. It works, the shares are mounted whenever I need them, as they should.

The problem I find is that my mount list grows endlessly. It starts with one "map auto_myshare" line, and more are added over time. I've got to see over 2000 identical mounts:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1s1 on / (apfs, local, read-only, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /System/Volumes/Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s5 on /private/var/vm (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /System/Volumes/Data/home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/Storage (exfat, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
/dev/disk3 on /Volumes/Backup (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_myshares on /Users/me/mnt (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

The problem is, at some point the system becomes unstable and I need to reboot it.

I've tried a number of things but nothing seems to prevent this list from growing:

- Disabled the Active Directory integration (otherwise auto_home was going nuts) and Symantec antivirus
- Played with large (3600) and small (30) values of `AUTOMOUNT_TIMEOUT` in `/etc/autofs.conf`
- Doing `automount -vc` adds another line
- Killing automount, autofsd

For reference, I've configured my `/etc/auto_master` with this line:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/me/mnt auto_myshares
```

and /etc/auto_myshares with:

```
share1      -fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners ://user:passwd@SERVER/share
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use `/etc/fstab` **with the net option**.

1 - Uncomment this line in `/etc/auto_master`:

```
/Network/Servers        -fstab
```

2 - Fill in fstab as root. For example:

```
server:/path ignoredmountpoint url net,noowners,url==smb://user:passwd@server/path
...
```

3 - Run `sudo automount -vc`

This way, everything is mounted in /Network/Servers automatically on demand and I don't observe multiple mount points anymore.

I think **the net option** is what makes this work, because I had already tried using fstab before with the same result as an autofs map (i.e. multiple mounts per mountpoint).

Comment: Can you give more details about what each field does, and an example of them filled in. For instance, why `server:/path` then again in `url==`, and what does `url` mean in `url net`. What does `ignoredmountpoint` mean?

Comment: This answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/76714/15131 also says `soft` should be used as an option. Also for other readers, this does not mount at `/Volumes/share` but at `/System/Volumes/Data/Network/Servers/server/share`